# Page number request doesn't change for site when scraping with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to extract some information from a specific page using Python and Beautiful Soup. I figured out that `request.get(url)` doesn't change page even when I request different pages.

In below line I define which page I am scraping, all returns `pagenumber=1`, even when I tried with `pagenumber=2` it starts from the first page and scrapes just the fist page.

```
    activepage = soup.find('ul', id= 'pagination').li.string
    print "Page Number: " + activepage
```

I tested my code on other pages and it works fine, but on this specific page I can't loop through different pages. Can anyone tell me what is the exact problem with this page and what is the solution?

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):

page_number = 1

while page_number <= max_pages:
    url = "http://munich.eventful.com/events/categories/festivals_parades#!page_number=" + str(page_number) + "&category=festivals_parades"
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    # just get the code, no headers or anything
    plain_text = source_code.text
    # BeautifulSoup objects can be sorted through easy
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    category = soup.find('li', id = 'breadcrumb-label').string
    activepage = soup.find('ul', id= 'pagination').li.string
    print "Page Number: " + activepage
    for mylist in soup.findAll('li', {'class': 'clearfix'}):
        link = mylist.find('a', {'data-ga-label': 'Event Title'})
        if (link is not None):
            href = link.get('href')
            title = link.string  # just the text, not the HTML
            location = mylist.find("div", {"class": "event-meta"}).strong.string
            date = mylist.find("div", {"class": "event-meta"}).span.string
            print(title, category, href, date, location)

    page_number += 1

trade_spider(8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should  get what you want:

```
def trade_spider(max_pages):
    for page_number in range(1, max_pages + 1):
        url = "http://munich.eventful.com/events/categories/festivals_parades?page_number={}".format(page_number)
        print(url)
        # just get the code, no headers or anything
        plain_text = requests.get(url).content
        # BeautifulSoup objects can be sorted through easy
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        category = soup.find('li', id='breadcrumb-label').string
        for mylist in soup.findAll('li', {'class': 'clearfix'}):
            link = mylist.find('a', {'data-ga-label': 'Event Title'})
            if link is not None:
                href = link.get('href')
                title = link.string  # just the text, not the HTML
                location = mylist.find("div", {"class": "event-meta"}).strong.string
                date = mylist.find("div", {"class": "event-meta"}).span.string
            print(title, category, href, date, location)
```

I just needed to change the base url:

```
http://munich.eventful.com/events/categories/festivals_parades?page_number={}
```

It is also simpler just to loop in `range(1, max_pages + 1)`

Output:

```
trade_spider(3)

http://munich.eventful.com/events/categories/festivals_parades?page_number=1
Rockavaria 2015 - Freitag Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/rockavaria-2015-freitag-/E0-001-077521284-1 Kleine Olympiahalle May 29
Rockavaria 2015 - Reiseangebote Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/rockavaria-2015-reiseangebote-/E0-001-077133997-3 Kleine Olympiahalle May 29 - May 31
Rockavaria 2015 - Samstag Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/rockavaria-2015-samstag-/E0-001-082047581-8 Kleine Olympiahalle May 30
Ermittelt wird im Cafe`Mellow München... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/ermittelt-wird-im-cafemellow-mnchen-tatort-im-ma-/E0-001-083732894-3 Cafe Bar Mellow München May 24
Ermittelt wird im Cafe`Mellow München... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/ermittelt-wird-im-cafemellow-mnchen-tatort-im-ma-/E0-001-083934156-8 Cafe Bar Mellow München May 31
Ermittelt wird im Cafe`Mellow München... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/ermittelt-wird-im-cafemellow-mnchen-tatort-im-ma-/E0-001-084050435-8 Cafe Bar Mellow München May 25
ORGANIC DANCE MUSIC FESTIVAL Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/organic-dance-music-festival-/E0-001-076992422-8 Zenith Jun 13
Organic Dance Music Festival with Tal... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/organic-dance-music-festival-tale-us-dixon-david-/E0-001-082231599-0 Zenith Jun 13
13. aDevantgarde-Festival »humus« Wur... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/13-adevantgardefestival-humus-wurzel3-doppelkonz-/E0-001-082515660-8 Gasteig Jun 14
http://munich.eventful.com/events/categories/festivals_parades?page_number=2
Festive Concerts: Palace Schleißheim Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/festive-concerts-palace-schleiheim-/E0-001-082934543-1 Schloss Schleissheim Jul  5
Festive Concerts: Palace Schleißheim Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/festive-concerts-palace-schleiheim-/E0-001-082934542-2 Schloss Schleissheim Jun 19
Festive Concerts: Palace Schleißheim Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/festive-concerts-palace-schleiheim-/E0-001-082957294-7 Schloss Schleissheim Aug  2
Festive Concerts: Palace Schleißheim Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/festive-concerts-palace-schleiheim-/E0-001-082957292-9 Schloss Schleissheim Jun 14
Tollwood Festival: Patti Smith Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/tollwood-festival-patti-smith-/E0-001-080907608-3 Tollwood Jul 13
VLAD IN TEARS - FREE AND EASY FESTIVAL Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/vlad-tears-free-and-easy-festival-/E0-001-083500016-8 Backstage Jul 25
COMBICHRIST - FREE AND EASY FESTIVAL Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/combichrist-free-and-easy-festival-/E0-001-083499106-7 Backstage Jul 25
13. aDevantgarde-Festival »humus« Spi... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/13-adevantgardefestival-humus-spinnen-/E0-001-082515659-2 Gasteig Jun 15
Barber & Cook - EOS Festival Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/barber-cook-eos-festival-/E0-001-081892354-3 Taufkirchen (Vils) Jun  4
http://munich.eventful.com/events/categories/festivals_parades?page_number=3
Yaz Aski Indoor Festival - Mabel Mati... Festivals http://eventful.com/events/yaz-aski-indoor-festival-mabel-matiz-ilyas-yalcintas-karga-/E0-001-083819488-4 Muffathalle Jun  6
Keep It Low Festival 2015 MÜNCHEN Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/keep-low-festival-2015-mnchen-/E0-001-083819658-1 Feierwerk Oct 16
10. Oberhachinger Classic Jazz Festiv... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/10-oberhachinger-classic-jazz-festival-3-tag-/E0-001-080921159-8 Bürgersaal Beim Forstner Jun 13
10. Oberhachinger Classic Jazz Festiv... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/10-oberhachinger-classic-jazz-festival-2-tag-/E0-001-080921158-9 Bürgersaal Beim Forstner Jun 12
Kool & Kabul - EOS Festival Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/kool-kabul-eos-festival-/E0-001-083947944-5 Crazy Town Jun  4
10. Oberhachinger Classic Jazz Festiv... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/10-oberhachinger-classic-jazz-festival-1-tag-e-/E0-001-080921157-0 Bürgersaal Beim Forstner Jun 11
Mellow Monks - Psychedelic Happiness ... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/mellow-monks-psychedelic-happiness-festival-201-/E0-001-078583630-3 Munich, Bayern, Germany Jun 12
Organic Dance Music Festival MÜNCHEN ... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/organic-dance-music-festival-mnchen-freimann-/E0-001-081520443-8 Zenith & Kesselhaus + dazwischenliegende Freifl... Jun 13
aDevantgarde Festival: Young Lions Re... Festivals http://munich.eventful.com/events/adevantgarde-festival-young-lions-reloaded-/E0-001-083294075-9 Club Milla Jun 13
```

Comment: Thank you @Padriac for your reply. It works. Can you explain what is the difference between "?" and "#!" which caused the problem in base url?

Comment: @Bruce, I looked at the source and if you check the pagination `class=paging clearfix ajax` you can see the links there, i.e page 2 `/events/categories/festivals_parades?page_number=2`